# Retrieve parent and children of firebase field

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get a parent value of a field in Firebase database along with its children. [image: firebase database]
for clarification:

I want to loop through the Snapshot to find the user who want to login by his or her ID, after that I want to get the parent of that id (i.e. is the user female or male) after that I want to get the canton and name.

so what I am doing is:

```
database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
rootRef = database.getReference();
users = rootRef.child("Users");
```

and then

```
users.orderByChild("name").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            if (child.getValue().equals(curUser.getUid())) {
                String gender = child.getKey().toString();
                currentPolUser.setuGender(gender);
                currentPolUser.setuName(child.child("Name").getValue().toString());
                Log.d("FirebaseUsers", "SUCCESSSSSS: "+currentPolUser.getuName() + " " + currentPolUser.getuGender());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

The problem is `child.getValue()` returns an object that can't be compared to the User id string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 ref.child("Users").orderByChild("name").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String gender = child.getKey();
                for(DataSnapshot finalChild : child.getChildren()){
                    if (finalChild.getKey().equals(curUser.getUid())) {
                        HashMap<String, Object> map = (HashMap<String, Object>) finalChild.getValue();
                        String name = (String) map.get("name");
                        currentPolUser.setuGender(gender);
                        currentPolUser.setuName(name);
                        Log.d("FirebaseUsers", "SUCCESSSSSS: "+currentPolUser.getuName() + " " + currentPolUser.getuGender());

                        Log.e("TTT", name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```